# Spring AMQP: how to avoid manual declaration of many queues?

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

Having created a basic spring-amqp setup, I see that for every type of message I want to send (using message POJOs), I need to declare the queue in the spring config.

So for every pair of these:

```
amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("queue1", new MessageType1(...));

@RabbitListener(queues = "queue1")
public void handleMessage(MessageType1 msg) {...}
```

I need an entry in the spring config like this:

```
<rabbit:queue name="queue1"/>
```

This seems redundant to me. If I think of the queues like HTTP urls, than it's enough to declare a controller with `@RequestMapping("/some-url")`, it's not necessary to than also declare `/some-url` elsewhere in the config.

If eventually the application will have many types of messages going through the broker, that will just bloat the config.

I see two ways to avoid this:

1. Automatically declaring the queues for each annotated listener endpoint. i.e if there is an annotated listener endpoint `@RabbitListener(queues = "hello")`, then it can be inferred that a queue `hello` should be declared. I thought this might already be the case, but when I removed the queue from the context config, I got the following error:

   ```
   WARN  BlockingQueueConsumer - Failed to declare queue:hello
   WARN  BlockingQueueConsumer - Queue declaration failed; retries left=2
   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[hello]
       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:479)
       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:400)
       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1022)
   ```
2. Using different message POJOs on the same queue. So sending both `MessageType1` and `MessageType2` on `queue1`, each reaching a different endpoint, based on payload type. In effect this creates sort of a single "application queue", similar to a database schema:

   ```
   @RabbitListener(queues = "queue1")
   public void handleMessage1(MessageType1 msg) {...}

   @RabbitListener(queues = "queue1")
   public void handleMessage2(MessageType2 msg) {...}
   ```

   Trying this approach yielded an error.

Is any of the above currently possible with spring-amqp (1.4.0), and if so how?

Comment: Have you looked into [Remoting via AMQP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#remoting)? It uses the mechanism you imply in (2). I do not know the context, but this might work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not currently possible to auto-declare `@RabbitListener` queues but it sounds like a reasonable request. Of course, declaring the queue alone might not be enough; while it will be bound to the default exchange `""` with the queue name as a routing key, any more sophisticated binding would require additional configuration anyway.

Using the queue name as a routing key with the default exchange is not considered best practice because it couples the producer and consumer. But I do recognize it is used at times, so please enter a [New Feature JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and we'll consider it.

BTW, you can also use `@Bean`s alongside the listeners to avoid XML config.

Your second request can be implemented by a delegating message listener:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queue1")
public void handleMessage(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Type1) {
        delegate.type1((Type1) o);
    }
    else if (o instanceof Type2) {
        delegate.type2((Type2) o);
    } 
}
```

I have been thinking of providing such a listener (in a more generic way). Again, please open a new feature issue.

**EDIT**

Both of these features are now available in the 1.5 release. [`@QueueBinding`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/_introduction.html#__rabbitlistener_improvements) and [Class-level `@RabbitListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/_introduction.html#_class_level_rabbitlistener).

Comment: I'm starting to understand that I should think of queues more like database tables than REST URLs. If we think about them this way - it makes sense for a schema DDL file to exist somewhere. However, that being said, with Hibernate using annotations we wouldn't write such a DDL, but rather have it inferred from our POJO annotations. Perhaps a similar approach can be adopted here, where the listener annotations can provide the details for the queue. Anyway I'll move the discussion to JIRA.

Comment: Auto-declaring is possible now, starting with Spring AMQP 1.5.0, which is currently in M1. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.M1/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven